# MySQL Connector/C++

Tags: c++, mysql, c

I'am doing a program that deals with connecting to mysql server and accessing or writing data. I am wondering whether to do the connector part using connector for c or c++. I have heard that c connector is more stable than the c++ connector. Please do help me choose..
MySQL Connector/C or MySQL Connector/C++?

Comment: Are there two different connectors for C and C++? Or you're talking about C API and C++ MySQL connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the language you're the most comfortable with, and use the connector for that language.

Comment: i have not decided yet to whether program in c or c++ that is y the delemma... is c connector more stable than the c++ thats all i need to know..

Comment: wen i read about it, the connector/c++ and MySQL++ are from 2 different sources... http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/ this page explains it..

Comment: @Prasanth Madhavan Indeed, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I use `mysqlpp` (a C++ API for MySQL), and it works fine.  As far as I can tell there is little if anything that cannot be done effectively and efficiently using this API that can be done better in pure C.  I say use C++, if you're comfortable enough with that language.  Specifically regarding stability, it seems fine.

There are some fairly obscure deficiencies, such as a lack of support for true asynchronous operation, but the C interface doesn't really solve this problem either (PostgreSQL does).